# How can I publish a map using ros2 launch?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I want to show a map in rviz2, how can I use ros2 launch to publish a map?

I have read this repo: https://answers.ros.org/question/406036/how-to-publish-map-in-ros2-galactic/
and use the CLT to show a map in rviz2, but how can I use ros2 launch?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!  Please spend some time going through [the official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/index.html). Thank you for your kind cooperation.